# Angular 10 setting selected option value in dropdown list in edit component

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, angular-material

in angular and asp.net application, I have an edit form in my component with multiple select options in  dropdown list, where display all data in edit form except  dropdown list  fields is displayed as empty with all dropdown list values not with formerly stored dropdown list value.
So I need to set the selected option value in the dropdown list when i go to the edit form in edit.component.html.
this is my edit.component.ts

```js
  id: number;
  userForm: FormGroup;
  Charity: Charities;
  Charities: Charities[];
  users: Users[];
  Cities: City[];
  Categories: Category[];
  selected: any;
  Regions: Region[];
  constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,private route: Router,private fb : FormBuilder, private CharityService : CharityService,private toastr: ToastrService , private RegisterService : AccountService, private router : ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var userId = this.router.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.setForm(userId);
    this.CharityService.GetAllCategories().then(res => this.Categories = res as Category[])
    this.CharityService.GetAllRegions().then(res => this.Regions = res as Region[])
    this.CharityService.GetAllUsers().then(res => this.users = res as Users[]); 
    this.users = [];
  }
  get editFormData() { return this.userForm.controls; }


  private setForm(id:number) {
    this.CharityService.GetCharit(id).then(x => {

      this.Charity = x;
      this.userForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [this.Charity.id, [Validators.required]],
        name: [this.Charity.name, [Validators.required]],
        phone: [this.Charity.phone, [Validators.required]],
        SubCategoryId: [this.Charity.SubCategoryId, [Validators.required]],
        RegionId: [this.Charity.RegionId, [Validators.required]],
        CityId: [this.Charity.CityId, [Validators.required]],  
        Category:[this.Charity.Category, [Validators.required]],
      });
    });

  }
```

this is edit.component.html

for example formControlName="SubCategoryId"

```html
 <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="Categories" formControlName="SubCategoryId" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :!this.userForm.get('SubCategoryId').valid && this.userForm.get('SubCategoryId').touched}" [(value)]="selected" required>
<option selected value="" disabled class="dove">اختر التصنيف</option>
<option *ngFor="let cat of Categories" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.subCategoryName}}</option>
</select>
```

can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it´s works for me

```
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="SubCategoryId" #SubCategory formControlName="SubCategoryId">
   <option *ngFor="let cat of Categories; let i = index" [ngValue]="cat.id">
       {{cat.value}}
   </option>             
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected option value for the dropdown in the ts file in the following way:

```
this.userForm.controls.get('SubCategoryId').setValue('' + this.Charity.SubCategoryId + '');
```

Thanks

Comment: i get this error :-
RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
    at EditCharityComponent.ngOnInit

Comment: @MostafaGamal,  After the controls, have been created and values for the dropdown are bound then set the selected value for those dropdowns.

Comment: put a debugger and check that userForm has controls or remove controls and use get this.userForm.get('SubCategoryId')

Comment: i get this error :-
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'AbstractControl' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing that by the moment you bind control values, your lookup list still not loaded from the server.
to prove this first you'll have to fill your lists with dummy data e.g. `this.Categories = [1,2,3]`.

The solution to this is pretty simple:

Turn your ngOnInit to `async` function and `await` inside it the needed services, then you can patch the form values

```
async ngOnInit(): void {
        const userId = this.router.snapshot.params['id'];
        await Promise.all([
            this.CharityService.GetAllCategories().then(res => this.Categories = res as Category[]),
            this.CharityService.GetAllRegions().then(res => this.Regions = res as Region[]),
            this.CharityService.GetAllUsers().then(res => this.users = res as Users[])
        ]);

        this.setForm(userId);
        this.users = [];
    }
```

P.S. I used `Promise.all()` for parallel execute only, you can use await for every service call if you need to execute one by one, hope this solves your issue.

One more thing, a better approach is to initiate your form once, and the patch values:

```
private _initForm(){
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
        id: ['', [Validators.required]],
        name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
        SubCategoryId: ['', [Validators.required]],
        RegionId: ['', [Validators.required]],
       CityId: ['', [Validators.required]],  
       Category:['', [Validators.required]],
  });
```

}

then call it in your `ngOnInit`

```
async ngOnInit(): void {
    _initForm();
    //rest of code
}
```

then inside your `setForm` function you should patch values only like below:

`this.userForm.patchValue({ id : newValue });`

Comment: Not work for you?
Indeed I feel sorry for the time I spent answering your question, good luck brother.